# How to get the result of QDialog::show()?

Tags: qt, exec, show

I want to convert `exec` usages to `show` method in my projects. Because, when I use the `exec` for windows (dialogs) I can not open another window. This is the basic difference between `exec()` and `show()` method.

The `exec` and `show` work in different ways and I am wondering how can I change the below code with using `show()` instead of `exec()`.

For example:

```
int result = exampleWindow->exec();

if ( result == QDialogButtonBox::Ok )
{
    exampleWindow->UpdateCalibrationData(&data);
    exampleWindow->UpdateFilterData(&filterData);
    exampleWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`show()` shows a non-modal window;

`exec()` shows a modal window.

If you want to get the result of `show()`, then go with Qt signals/slots:

```
ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    // Assuming the QDialogButtonBox name is "buttonBox":
    connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));
}
```

**MainWindow.h**:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
private slots:
    void updateData();
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    connect(exampleWindow, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(updateData()));
}

void MainWindow::updateData()
{
    // Your code:
    exampleWindow->UpdateCalibrationData(&data);
    exampleWindow->UpdateFilterData(&filterData);
    exampleWindow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have a question for you, is it safe to use same time exec and show method. For example, first use show and than for the loop use exec? what do you think ?

Comment: What's the point of using `exec()` and `show()` *simultaneously*? If you mean *alternation* of these two methods for different cases, then yes, technically it is safe (though be careful, because signals for `exec()` will also be fired). But I'm not sure why would you need the loop for `exec()`.

Answer (score 1):

`show()` simply makes the dialog window visible. It is a `QWidget` method.

`exec()`, when provided in a class, always spins an event loop. In case of dialogs specifically, it'll make the dialog visible before spinning the event loop.

You could implement a functionally equivalent `exec()` yourself, as follows:

```
void myExec(QDialog * dialog) {
  QStateMachine sm;
  QState s1(&sm), s2(&sm);
  sm.setInitialState(&s1);
  QEventTransition transition(dialog, QEvent::Close);
  s2.addTransition(&transition);
  QEventLoop loop;
  QObject::connect(&s2, &QState::entered, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
  sm.start();
  dialog->show();
  loop.exec();
}
```

Generally speaking, you should never use `exec()` to create a nested event loop, since you're exposing a lot of your own code to possible reentrancy requirements. In case of dialogs, it is always possible to show a modal dialog box without using `exec()`, so there's really no point to it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. This is a good solution for me but i have a question for you the loop is terminates when application is closed. But i want to terminate the loop when the QDialog is closed. How can i do that ?

Comment: @EmreS That's what the `exec()` in the answer is doing, and that's what `QDialog::exec()` is doing as well. If you have another question, please post it separately.

Comment: [here another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399044/how-can-i-terminate-qstatemachine-when-qdialog-is-closed)

Answer (score 0):

exec() method shows modal dialog as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec)

You can use for example [closeEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent) of your dialog. In it you can write something like:

```
void ExmpleWin::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (/*Your condition*/) {
        emit signalUpdateMyData();
        event->accept();
    }
}
```

Also you have to connect signal signalUpdateMyData() with apropriate slot where you can make:

```
exampleWindow->UpdateCalibrationData(&data);
exampleWindow->UpdateFilterData(&filterData);
exampleWindow();
```