# How can I terminate QStateMachine when QDialog is closed?

Tags: qt, loops, qstatemachine

I have a QDialog and QStateMachine. This loop terminates when the all aplication is closed but i want to terminate loop when Qdialog is closed. How can i do that?

```
  QStateMachine sm;
  QState s1(&sm), s2(&sm);
  sm.setInitialState(&s1);
  QEventTransition transition(dialog, QEvent::Close);
  s2.addTransition(&transition);
  QEventLoop loop;
  QObject::connect(&s2, &QState::entered, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
  sm.start();
  dialog->show();
  loop.exec();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`QFinalState`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfinalstate.html) class for this. At [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfinalstate.html#details) example shown usage `QPushButton` with exit. You just need to connect it with [`finished()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#finished) signal for example.

**UPD**

Some usage example:

MainWinow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, private Ui::MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

private:
    QDialog *dialog;
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);

    dialog = new QDialog;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // Open dialog after push button was clicked
    if (!dialog)
        dialog = new QDialog;

    QEventLoop loop;
    QStateMachine machine;
    QState *s1 = new QState();

    QFinalState *s2 = new QFinalState();
    s1->addTransition(dialog, SIGNAL(finished(int)), s2);

    connect(&machine, QStateMachine::finished, [&loop]{
        qDebug() << "Finished";
        loop.quit();
    });

    machine.addState(s1);
    machine.addState(s2);
    machine.setInitialState(s1);
    machine.start();


    dialog->show();
    loop.exec();

    qDebug() << "Really finished";
}
```

So we create `QEventLoop`, `QStateMachine` and add states(init state and final state). Then connect `QDialog::finished()` signal with transition to final state and connect `QStateMachine::finished()` signal with slot where event loop will be stoped. Then show `QDialog` and start `QStateMachine`.

At console will print:

> Finished
>
> Realy finished

Comment: this is okay but i have a loop in above code, i want to stop loop when QDialog is closed?

Comment: You can add `QEventLoop` as class atribute, connect [`finished()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#finished) signal of `QStateMachine` with slot where you call [`quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html#quit) slot of `QEventLoop`

Comment: @EmreS see update. I attach some example of usage i described

Comment: thank you i appreciated. This is the best solution for me !!